# How to extract specific tag content in XML file if there are other tags with the same name inside another tag in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

Currently, I'm working in parsing XML files in Java using DOM. But I have faced a problem in how to extract specific tag content from XML file if there are other tags with the same name inside another tag as the following scenario :

```
<file>
    <sub-file>
        <a> ....</a>
        <b> ....</b>
        <c> ....</c>
    </sub-file>

    <a> ..... some data here ....</a>
    <b> ..... some data here ....</b>
    <c> ..... some data here ....</c>

    <image>
        <a> ....</a>
        <b> ....</b>
        <c> ....</c>
    </image>
</file>
```

So how could I extract a,b,c tags that aren't inside another (inside sub-file or image)? I tried so far this code:

```
    File xmlfile=new File(path);
            factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder=  factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document= builder.parse(xmlfile);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            filelist= document.getElementsByTagName("file");
            for(int o=0;o<filelist.getLength();o++)
            {
                Node nNode = filelist.item(o);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {

                    Element element = (Element) nNode;
                        for (int a=0; a<element.getElementsByTagName("file").getLength(); a++)
                    {   

                            tagA=element.getElementsByTagName("a").item(a).getTextContent();

                            tagB=element.getElementsByTagName("b").item(a).getTextContent();

                            tagC=element.getElementsByTagName("c").item(a).getTextContent();

                    }       
                }
            }// loop
        }
```

This code print all the tags a,b,c 3 times (inside file, sub-file and image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `getElementsByTagName()`. Instead, navigate the DOM tree yourself:

```
Node fileNode = filelist.item(o);
for (Node child = fileNode.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        switch (child.getNodeName()) {
            case "a":
                tagA = child.getTextContent();
                break;
            case "b":
                tagB = child.getTextContent();
                break;
            case "c":
                tagC = child.getTextContent();
                break;
            default:
                // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you can also look into using XPath:

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

tagA = xpath.evaluate("a", fileNode);
tagB = xpath.evaluate("b", fileNode);
tagC = xpath.evaluate("c", fileNode);
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't think in this way to look for children for tags. Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Element.getElementsByTagName(String)` returns all *descendant* nodes with with the provided tag name, not just the immediate children. You can navigate the tree by using `getChildNodes()` and iterating on the returned `NodeList` or using `getFirstChild()` and iterating using `getNextSibling()`.

If you are not limited to using just DOM, you can also use XPath to select the appropriate nodes, i.e. `//file/a`.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. I will search more about XPath parsing.